# For-loop over several variables from a single list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a loop like this

```
newList = [a + b for a,b in list[::2], list[1::2]]
```

meaning, take two consecutive entries from a list, do something with them and put the into a new list.

How would that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) your two newly created lists:

```
newList = [a + b for a,b in zip(list[::2], list[1::2])]
```

You also do this in a somewhat more memory-efficient manner by using an iterator:

```
it = iter(list)
newList = [a + b for a, b in zip(it, it)]
```

or even more efficiently* by using the [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) function, which returns an iterator:

```
import itertools
it = iter(list)
newList = [a + b for a, b in itertools.izip(it, it)]
```

* at least under Python 2.x; in Python 3, as I understand it, `zip` itself returns an iterator.

**Note** that you really should never call a variable `list` as this clobbers the builtin `list` constructor.  This can cause confusing errors and is generally considered bad form.

Comment: I see. I tried your first suggestion and it works fine with a small data set. However, my list is a 5Mx4 array in reality and that takes >5G of memory ... is there any way to ... fundamentally optimize the procedure?

Comment: Using `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` will prevent an entire extra copy of the list from being created and then destroyed during the generation of `newList`'s value.  Other than that, well, you could **a)** do an in-place substitution on the original list and then crop it.. but you'd have to write it yourself using indices, and it might be noticeably slower; or **b)** use [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/).  I know little of numpy except that its main purpose in life is to make working with large arrays fast and convenient.

Comment: Also: if you don't actually need to have access to all of newList at once, you can turn the list comprehension `[a + b for ...]` into a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).  This way you can use the values of `newList` one by one and don't have to keep them all in memory at once.  If you do that using `newList = (a + b for a, b in itertools.izip(it, it))`, you won't end up using a significant amount of memory compared to the size of the list itself.

Comment: @McEnroe: Check the tutorial section on [iterators](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) for more background info if I'm getting ahead of you here.  Actually, reading the entire tutorial is a pretty good idea, it's quite well-written.

Comment: @McEnroe: Wait, 5 *gigs*?  In that case — assuming that you're reading this in from a file — you probably want to only read in part of the file at once.  I would probably do this by creating a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) that reads a line or a few at a time and yields single values or even pairs of values.  If you are also writing the results out to another file, you can process the whole thing with minimal memory requirements.

Comment: @intuited: Just tried running it again with izip. I had to cancel once it used up my 4G of ram.... I'll give numpy a try. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L=range(6)
>>> from operator import add
>>> map(add, L[::2], L[1::2])
[1, 5, 9]
```

alternatively you could use an iterator here

```
>>> L_iter = iter(L)
>>> map(add, L_iter, L_iter)
[1, 5, 9]
```

since you pass the same iterator twice, `map()` will consume two elements for each iteration

Another way to pass the iterator twice is to build a list with a shared reference. That avoids the temporary variable

```
>>> map(add, *[iter(L)]*2)
[1, 5, 9]
```

of course you can replace `add` with your own function

```
>>> def myfunc(a,b):
...     print "myfunc called with", a, b
...     return a+b
... 
>>> map(myfunc, *[iter(L)]*2)
myfunc called with 0 1
myfunc called with 2 3
myfunc called with 4 5
[1, 5, 9]
```

And it's easy to expand to 3 variables or more

```
>>> def myfunc(*args):
...     print "myfunc called with", args
...     return sum(args)
... 
>>> map(myfunc, *[iter(L)]*3)
myfunc called with (0, 1, 2)
myfunc called with (3, 4, 5)
[3, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip and Map come in handy here.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> list(zip(a, b))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> list(map <operation>, (zip(a, b)))
>>> ...
```

Or in your case,

```
>>> list(map(lambda n: n[0] + n[1], (zip(a, b))))
[5, 7, 9]
```

There's definitely a better way to pass the plus operation to the map. Feel free to add to it, anyone!

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, this is not quite what the OP wants to do.  I understood that the goal was to get `[(1 + 2), (3 + 4), (5 + 6)]` from `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Comment: @intuited got it right. (Technically the "source" list consists of objects that have a __add__ method defined but that shouldn't make difference as far as I understand it.)